# If $T:V\to W$ is linear, there is $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ s.t. $\langle\alpha ,Tv\rangle =\langle T^*\alpha ,v\rangle$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ and $W$ two vector spaces. I know that in infinite dimension, if $T\in \mathcal L(V,W)$ is a linear map, there is $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ s.t. for all $\alpha \in W^*$ and all $v\in V$,
$$\left\langle\alpha ,Tv\right\rangle_{W^*,W}=\left\langle T^*\alpha ,v\right\rangle_{V^*,V},$$
where $V^*$ denote the dual of $V$ and $\left\langle\theta  ,x\right\rangle_{A^*,A}:=\theta (x)$ is the duality bracket. I know that it's not exactly the statement, since $T^*$ may not be defined on the whole space. But let suppose that for simplification.

---

I tried to proof that whenever $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional. I could provide a proof whenever $V$ and $W$ has same dimension, and I had to use the fact that $V^*\cong W^*$. So, I was wondering, is it also true when then don't have the same dimension ? I would say yes but : if $\dim (V)<\dim(W)$ then the adjoint of $T^*$ will be define only on a subspace of $W^*$ and if $\dim(W)<\dim (V)$, then $T$ won't have a adjoint but if $U\subset V$ is a subspace with same dimension than $W$, then $\mathcal T|_{U}$ will have an adjoint.

---

Do you agree with this or am I mistaken something ? I have a doubt, because in infinite dimension, $D(T^*)$ (the space where $T^*$ is well defined) should be dense in $W^*$, whereas, if $\dim(V)<\dim(W)$, since $T^*$ is defined on a subspace of $W^*$ of dimension strictly smaller that $W^*$, and thus won't be dense.

Comment: For future reference, the symbols `<` and `>` are binary relations, and are typeset by adding a little extra space on either side.  For pointy braces, the correct commands in TeX / MathJax are `\langle` and `\rangle`, which are typeset as $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

Comment: If $V,W$ are two vector spaces and $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ is a linear map, you can always define a map $T^{*} \colon W^{*} \rightarrow V^{*}$ by $T^{*}(\alpha)(v) := \alpha(T(v))$ (where $\alpha \in W^{*}$ and $v \in V$). This is well-defined and linear and satisfies by definition $\left< \alpha, Tv \right> = \left< T^{*}(\alpha), v \right>$. This has nothing to do with whether $V,W$ are finite dimensional or not or whether they have the same dimension. This even works when $V,W$ are normed spaces and you take into account only continuous linear functionals and maps.

Comment: The complication with the domain of definition you are alluding to arise when $V,W$ are Hilbert spaces (so they come with an inner product) and you use the inner product bracket and not the duality bracket. Even then, if $V,W$ are finite dimensional (whether they have the same dimension or not), there are no problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue whatsoever. If $T:V\to W$, you define $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ by 
$$
(T^*f)(v)=f(Tv).
$$
Since $T$ is defined in all of $V$, this works for any $f\in W^*$, so $T^*$ is defined in all of $W^*$.